# Probability of at most two aces

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am dealt 7 cards from a standard pack. I want to find the probability of being dealt at most two aces by using combinations.  I believe the calculation looks like this:

$$\frac{\binom{4}{2} \binom{48}{5}+\binom{4}{1} \binom{48}{6} +\binom{4}{0} \binom{48}{7}}{\binom{52}{7}}=\frac{7689}{7735}=0.994053005817... .$$

Is this the correct solution? Thanks

Comment: That looks good except for a typo in third term of numerator $4C0.48C\color{Red}{6}$

Comment: make the 6 a 7.

Comment: It is worth noting explicitly that this is a hypergeometric problem.
Using the CDF for this distribution in R, the statement 'phyper(2, 4, 48, 7)' returns 0.994053.

Answer (score 0):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

As has been pointed out in comments, this calculation (as corrected) is correct.